# RETURNING ... INTO ... clause throwing an error with Oracle and ColdFusion

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle10g, coldfusion-9

Here is the query I am running.

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasource="mydatasource">
    INSERT INTO 
        myTable (myfield) 
    VALUES 
        (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myValue#" />)
    RETURNING
        id INTO <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#LOCAL.myid#" />    
</cfquery>
```

The error I am getting is `ORA-00439: feature not enabled: RETURNING clause from this client type`

I've run across a feature in cfquery called [GENERATEDKEY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html), I think this can be used to mitigate any database server settings, which I don't have access to. However I can't seem to get GENERATEDKEY to return my primary key instead I get something like AAFO9cAAEAAB8vYAAH, which is the Oracle rowid...

Comment: What is your client version ? does your query work from sql*plus ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you linked, there isn't a generatedkey member of the query result. there's a generated_key for mySQL, but for oracle it's ROWID, although the docs say this "Oracle only. The ID of an inserted row. This is not the primary key of the row, although you can retrieve rows based on this ID." I'm not sure how to map from one to the other though. If you leave out the RETURNING part of the statement, do you get anything for ROWID?

Comment: OP is getting an `ORA-00439`. The `ID` is a column name (that's how you use returning clause in oracle). If it weren't so, he would have got an `ORA-00904 invalid identifier`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with coldfusion, and there may be some simple solution.
But if not, a workaround could be to create a stored procedure that is using the `returning clause` and retuns it.
This way you can call the stored procedure instead.

```
create or replace function insert_my_table(my_value varchar2) return number is
   i number;
begin
   insert into my_table (value_col_name) values (my_value) returning id into i;
   return i;
end insert_my_table;
```